# Easiest way on multiplying number to percent value

Tags: .net, vb.net, function

Hello :) I have a formula like this

```
Dim numbHolder as Decimal = 'Anything i will send'
If val(txtbox1.text) <= 9 then
 txtbox2.text = numbHolder * (0.0 & val(txtbox1.text))
else
 txtbox2.text = numbHolder * (0. & val(txtbox1.text))
end if
```

is there an easiest way or function that i can use to multiply any number in percentage?
because in my scenario i have to check it first if the number is not greater than 9
so that i can use correct formula like `0.09` not `0.9` and so on..

Comment: You need to get the percentage of `numbHolder` based on what is in `txtbox1.Text`? Basic math: `txtbox2.Text = numberHolder * (Val(txtbox1.Text) / 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would avoid mixing `Val` and calculations in the one place. Try separating the parsing and populating text fields with the calculation like this:

```
' Parse/Load Values
Dim numbHolder As Decimal = 10 'Anything i will send'
Dim percentage As Decimal = CType(Val(txtbox1.Text), Decimal) / 100

' Calculate
Dim result = numbHolder * percentage

' Populate
txtbox2.Text = result.ToString()
```

Comment: What are the problems that may occur if I put it in one place? Enlighten me good sir.

Comment: @CrushSundae - Bugs. Lots of Bugs. Separating code like this is good practice to make the code clear, readable, and maintainable.